# angular4 - create a global variable that can be also accessed in views

Tags: angular

Is it possible to create a global variable that can be accessed from both components and views?

At the moment i created a global.ts file like this:

```
export const GlobalVariable = Object.freeze({
  BASE_API_URL: 'http://www.asdf.com/'
});
```

And then i have to import it in every component:

```
import { GlobalVariable } from '../shared/global';
```

Then i can use "GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL" in those components. There are two problems with it i dont like. First the part that i have to import it in every single component, is it possible to do a import for all components once? But actually thats a problem i can live with. The bigger problem is that i can seem to access that variable in my html files. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: "i can seem to access that variable in my html files" ? what do you mean ? Why it is a problem to access variable from html file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can to some extent, yes. You can create a service, define a property in that service, and then you can access that property from any component or any template ... as long as the service is injected into the component.

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

Component/template:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({ 
 template: ` 
  <div> 
    <h2>Data: {{ dataService.serviceData }} </h2> 
  </div> 
  `
})


export class A {

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {
     console.log(dataService.serviceData);
  } 
}
```

But notice that you *do* need to import the service with the imports statement and inject the service using the constructor in every component that needs it.

Comment: Is there any way to create a global variable without using service? Or is service a good way to create a global variable? Can you describe it further? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bit hacky but using pipe works really well. It saves you from repeating injection or variable binding in each component.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'global',
})
export class GlobalVariablePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any): object {
        return GlobalVariable;
    }
}
```

Then, once imported in your module, you can simply use the pipe as follows:

```
{{(''|global).BASE_API_URL}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, your template is scoped to the component class, i.e. you can only access anything declared or visible within your component class. You can't access anything in the global scope, for example, in your html template file, if you do

`{{ JSON.parse('{"message": "Hello World"}') }}`

You will see `Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined` or something like that

So to access that global variable in your template, you have to import it into your component class everytime

Comment: Ok, but how do i access this global variable in my template? Even if i import and write {{GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL}} in my template then i don't get anything displayed.

Comment: that's strange, I don't why it does not show anything, try creating a new variable say `url` in your component, and assign `GlobalVariable.BASE_API_UR` to it, then access `url` in your template.

Comment: yep, that works but it doesent seem like the best solution. i can live with importing the file in every component but if i have to redefine each line into a variable every time it loses its original point