# AngularJS use a global variable within a template for orderBy ng-repeat value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I'm working on a angular app which I do not have access to the source of the app only to the component html code.
I want to re-order a array with a custom function, but I'm not sure it's possible to access global variables within the template.

This works and sorts the fields by the value of "name" property.

```
<div ng-repeat="$field in $fields | orderBy:'name' track by $field.name " >
   <input ng-model="$item[$field.name] " />
</div>
```

If I try this, this will not work

> Not Work
>
> ```
> <script>var orderByProperty = 'name'; </script>
> <div ng-repeat="$field in $fields | orderBy:orderByProperty track by $field.name " >
>    <input ng-model="$item[$field.name] " />
> </div>
> ```

How can I access a global variables from within the angular template?

**I do not have access to the controller code of the app or main js file of the app, only to the html of component**. A solution how to order the array within the template will also solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular4 - create a global variable that can be also accessed in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638115/angular4-create-a-global-variable-that-can-be-also-accessed-in-views)

Comment: @nircraft I do not have access to the controller/main js file, only to html template so the question you mentioned is not relevant

Comment: really curious how that is possible that you can not add javascript...

Comment: `ng-repeat` is an AngularJS directive, not an Angular2 directive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-init to add some variables in html as:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl" ng-init="orderByProperty = 'name'">
    <div ng-repeat="$field in $fields | orderBy:orderByProperty track by $field.name ">
        <input ng-model="$field.name" />
    </div>        
</body>
```

Comment: can I add a function this way? seems like this does not work on function ( I want to order by function callback)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access a global variables from within the angular[JS] template?

You can't.

From the Docs:

> AngularJS expressions are like JavaScript expressions with the following differences:
>
> - **Context:** JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global window. In AngularJS, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions)